# Why does a virtual function with only a declaration result in a compiler error?

Tags: c++

I have this class,

```
class Base {
    public:
        void foo();
};

int main()
{
    Base b;
}
```

`main` will compile without any error, although `foo()` has no definition. But `b.foo();` will result in a compile error.

Moreover, even for `constructor` and `operator=`, I can just declare them without defining them, it'll compile as long as I don't trigger them.

## Question

Again, I add a virtual function into `Base`,

```
class Base {
    public:
        void foo();
        virtual void bar();  // no defition is gonna be provided.
};
```

Now, `main` cannot compile, instead I get an error:

```
undefined reference to vtable for Base
```

Well this confuses me a little bit, because previously, `main` could compile as long as `foo()` is not called, but now I add `bar()` and it's not called at all.

Why doesn't it compile in this case?

Comment: Could it be that not providing definitions allows the linker to link against different implementations? As for the virtual function, I would expect that the pure virtual function (virtual void bar() = 0) compiles without a problem. +1 : Very interesting question! :)

Comment: This is not an error from compiler, but from linker (so not compilation error, but linking error).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is strictly up to the compiler. No diagnostic is required for either case.

#### 10.3 Virtual functions [class.virtual]

> 9 A `virtual` function declared in a class shall be defined, or declared
>   pure (10.4) in that class, or both; but **no diagnostic is required**
>   (3.2). [emphasis mine]

To understand why this happens though, let's have a look at how it works.

Each translation unit generates an object file, each object file with exports (symbols it exported) and imports (symbols it wants).

The first example is simple - the imports only require `foo` when it is used. There's no reason for the linker to look for the symbol, so it doesn't.

The second one, with the `virtual` method, is a bit more complicated. Most compilers (if not all) required **valid virtual function tables**. That means that at link time, all classes that declared non-pure virtual methods would have to have those methods exported. This is stricter than the non-`virtual` case because the implementation doesn't actually know whether the function is called or not (it could be called polymorphically).

Comment: your answer is definitely better than mine. +1.

Comment: The point why I'm doing so is that I'm just curious about what would happen if a function is declared without definition, :-).

Comment: @Alcott okay then, kudos for being curious :)

Comment: can you get a link which `10.3 Virtual functions [class.virtual]` comes @Luchian Grigore , thinks anyway!

Answer (score 5):

First version can compile because the linker needn't search for the object `foo`. It's used nowhere.

But when you create a virtual function, the construction of the [vtable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table) (for dynamic dispatch) needs an address for the function `Base::bar` (it makes a reference to it) and therefore the linker needs to find an implementation of it.

Comment: So, in C++, as long as a `function` or `variable` is not used, I can just declare them without defining them, right?

Comment: I've just tried compiling the source from the question, but defining the bar() as a pure virtual function. Since the class is abstract base, no implementation is expected, so no vtable is created? The code compiles..

Answer (score 3):

When a polymorphic object (instance of a class with at least one virtual function) is created, it has to have a virtual table pointer that points to the virtual table. Each polymorphic class will have a virtual table that is constructed once. **It is up to the implementation of the compiler to allow the virtual table to be incomplete**. This table is populated based on virtual function definition.

If any virtual function is not implemented and the function is not pure virtual then some compilers give a compiler error as the virtual table is incomplete.

In the case of a simple (non-virtual) function, the function declaration will be ignored if it is never used. Even if it is used, we get a linker error and not compiler error.

Answer (score 1):

A virtual function declared in a class shall be defined, or declared pure in that class, or both(C++03 Standard).